# Strange counter variable in C inside loops, not changing back

Tags: c, counter

Pay attention to my counter variable.  Notice how I set it to 0 above the second while loop.  For some reason, my printf(counter) statement says that counter never gets reset to zero.  It just continues ++ing through the end of the file.  This totally messes up my logic for this program.  Any help?

```
ch=fgetc(fp);
while(ch != EOF)
{
    counter = 0;
    while(ch != '\n' && ch!=EOF)
    {
        char word[32] = "";

        // keeps track of the current run thru of the
        //  loop so we know what input we're looking at.
        counter = counter+1;
        while(ch != ' ' && ch!='\n' && ch!=EOF)
        {
            // the following block builds up a character
            //  array from the current "word" (separated
            //  by spaces) in the input file.
            int len = strlen(word);
            word[len] = ch;
            word[len+1] = '\0';
            ch = fgetc(fp);
        }

        // the following if-else block sets the variables
        //  TextA, TextB, and TextC to the appropriate Supply Types.
        //  this part may be confusing to read mentally, but not to
        //  trace; all it does is logically set TextA, B, and C.
        if(counter==1)
        {
            if(strlen(TextA)==0)
            {
                strcpy(TextA,word);
            }
            else if(strlen(TextB)==0 && strcmp(word,TextA)!=0 && strcmp(word,TextC)!=0)
            {
                strcpy(TextB,word);
            }
            else if(strlen(TextC)==0 && strcmp(word,TextA)!=0 && strcmp(word,TextB)!=0)
            {
                strcpy(TextC,word);
            }
        }

        printf("TextA:  %s, TextB:  %s, TextC:  %s  word:   %s \n",TextA,TextB,TextC,word);
        printf("i equals:  %d",counter);

        switch(counter)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Got in case 1.");
                if(strcmp(TextA,word)==0)
                {
                    SubTypeOption = 1;
                }
                else if(strcmp(TextB,word)==0)
                {
                    SubTypeOption = 2;
                }
                else if(strcmp(TextC,word)==0)
                {
                    SubTypeOption = 3;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                // We actually ultimately don't need to keep track of
                // the product's name, so we do nothing for case i=2.
                // Included for readibility.
                break;

            case 3:
                WholesalePrice = atof(word);
                break;

            case 4:
                WholesaleAmount = atoi(word);
                break;

            case 5:
                RetailPrice = atof(word);
                break;

            case 6:
                RetailAmount = atoi(word);
                break;
        } //End switch(counter)

        if(ch='\n')
            counter = 0;

        ch = fgetc(fp);

    }//End while(ch != '\n')

    //The following if-else block "tallys up" the total amounts of SubTypes bought and sold by the owner.

    if(SubTypeOption == 1)
    {
        SubType1OwnersCost = SubType1OwnersCost + (WholesalePrice*(float)WholesaleAmount);
        SubType1ConsumersCost = SubType1ConsumersCost + (RetailPrice *(float)RetailAmount);
    }
    else if(SubTypeOption == 2)
    {
        SubType2OwnersCost = SubType2OwnersCost + (WholesalePrice*(float)WholesaleAmount);
        SubType2ConsumersCost = SubType2ConsumersCost + (RetailPrice *(float)RetailAmount);
    }
    else if(SubTypeOption == 3)
    {
        SubType3OwnersCost = SubType3OwnersCost + (WholesalePrice*(float)WholesaleAmount);
        SubType3ConsumersCost = SubType3ConsumersCost + (RetailPrice *(float)RetailAmount);
    }

}//End while((ch = fgetc(fp))!= EOF)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're reading more than 15 characters and stepping outside `word` in your inner loop ?

Comment: Indented. Now... WTB some closing braces.

Comment: @WhozCraig If you have some superfluous patience, you could hand me some.

Comment: The "loop" that reads your string, apart from being the likely culprit that is overwriting your counter variable, is also a *classic* example of [The Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm). There are far better ways to do this.

Comment: @H2CO3 Hell no'z! One of us has to be on the hair-trigger, and you're far-better equipped (and more blunt) than I. But badly formatted code drives me nuts. Thankfully Xcode makes short-work of it (literally formats on the paste, so its quick =P).

Comment: I don't see how the loop messes up my counter variable.  I want my counter variable to be reset to zero before every running of the 2nd loop.  This is because I then use the counter variable after exiting the 2nd loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig Now that's the only real purpose of Xcode. Congrats, you just found one. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Heh, you didn't think I used it to write Objective-C, did you? Egads, man. I'm just too lazy to setup Eclipse with the Apple spin of llvm/clang. (and apparently it isn't trivial) =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Since I recognize your username, I'm sure you're active in the same tags as me :) But anyway, what I've chosen is Makefiles.

Comment: @user2055216 do the two `while` loops just close after the last printf  at the bottom of your code? also, What is `i` in all this?? Finally, what is the initial value of `ch` (hoping it is a read from your input file before this whole thing starts).

Comment: This question unfortunately still stands.  I know it's a big block of code, but could anyone at least take a look at the variable counter and consider why it might not be changing?

Comment: And.. out of the frying pan and into the fire. now you're doing this: `if(ch='\n') counter = 0`. Since **assigning** a newline to ch, then evaluating the result as a boolean expression will *always* be true, you're now resetting your counter *after every word*. Is there even the remotest chance we could see at least one set of data from the input file *and* the output your seeing, because as-written now, your counter should never exceed 1. **Ever**. Further, the *entire* `switch(counter){}` block can be eliminated from your post. it is not affecting your loop control whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts:

1. What is the type of `ch`?  It should be `int`.  (Note that `fgetc` returns `int`).  If it is `char` then the expression `ch != EOF` may not work as you expect it to.
2. If the input has more than 16 characters, I can very well see `counter` being reset.  It depends on the exact code your compiler has generated, but if you store something at `word[16]` (the seventeenth byte) and `counter` is on the stack immediately after `word`, you would start writing characters into the memory that contains `counter`.

Comment: No this is not the problem.  I am positive my input is not to exceed 16 characters.

Comment: Ok if I change from a char to an int, will that affect the rest of my algorithm?  Also I've had no problems running through these loops successfully, I can get output from this program just not the right output because of this stupid counter variable not being reset to zero !!!

Comment: @user2055216 would it be too much to ask that you post the *declarations* of `ch`, and while your at it, `i`, and the `fopen()` call for `fp`? Then change `ch` to be an `int` and try this all again. And no, changing it to `int` will not affect the algorithm (unless you perhaps count "making it work" under the umbrella of "affect").

Comment: I'm thinking this must have to do with the scope of the counter variable.  If it is changed above the second while loop, it doesn't actually change it at all in the scope of the problem.  Do I have to use pointers for this or something?... could I just make an int in memory which I know I will be able to easily change?

Comment: By the way I did put the declarations of ch, counter, and fp